# Why are $T^k(V)$ and $V^* \otimes... \otimes V^*$ just isomorphic?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

[In Lee, p.178](http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/lee.pdf), it is said that $T^k(V)$ is isomorphic to $V^* \otimes... \otimes V^*$. But is this not stronger? Isn't this an equality? I thought if $v_1,..., v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $\epsilon^1,...,\epsilon^n$ is its dual basis than $\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes...\otimes\epsilon^{i_n}$ is a basis of both $T^k(V)$ and $V^* \otimes... \otimes V^*$ no? So why just an isomorphism?

Comment: First, see the definition of $T^k(V)$ on pages 172-173. Then go to **Proposition 8.4(a)**  and find the proof for $k=2$, where you can see the actual isomorphism.

Comment: The version of my book that you linked to is a pirated early draft of the first edition, which somebody posted illegally on the internet. It's full of mistakes and comes with no guarantees.